# WordPress filters - Filter to control which page is being loaded

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to develope an password role protection on my web. What I need to achieve is to redirect visitors to the login `wp-login.php` when they try to enter an specific page if they are Suscriptors. WordPress don't gives us that option so I had to develop myself (I don't want to use external plugins).

I had the role filter, but I can't find the filter to control wich page is being loaded in order to redirect the visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your Function.php file.
[using `template_redirect` action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)

This action hook executes just before WordPress determines which template page to load. It is a good hook to use if you need to do a redirect with full knowledge of the content that has been queried.

```
function template_redirect_fn()
{
    //add you logic to perform your task  
    //Redirect page to login page 
    if(is_page ('about-us'))
    {

        $loginUrl = "LOGIN URL";
        wp_redirect($loginUrl);
         exit(); 
    }
    //if more then one page then used this 

    if( is_page( array( 'about-us', 'contact', 'management' ) )
      // about us, or contact, or management page is in view

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect_fn' );
```

[is_page(Page ID OR title OR slug of you want to check )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

Comment: This line is what I was needing `add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect_fn' );`. thanks a lot, it does the works perfect. One question, this template_redirect filter, when is invoked?

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal check this links https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect#Performing_a_redirect

Comment: Won't that function redirect everytime, even if you're already logged in? Is there any session info stored to stop that happening?

Comment: @Lee this is for demo not perfect code, you can add && ! is_user_logged_in() in if condition

Comment: @Lee i have add comment in function check that "add you logic to perform your task "